# Newline character insertion in Java

Tags: java, newline, chars

How can I insert a newline character in a Java applet program if I am using "label" instead of `System.out.println()`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

JLabel?

If you're using JLabel, you can use basic HTML in it

Try the following:

```
<html>Text<br>more text</html>
```

See this [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461112/panel-with-line-wrapping-and-line-breaking-in-java-swing/462836#462836)

And upvote it too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Put a `\n` in the string.

Like this:

```
String twoLineString = "first line\nsecond line";
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking for but you can use `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to get the line separator for your operating system.